# how to fix this looping?

Tags: c#, loops

I have a problem with a simple code. What i want to do is: For example if the user only gives a negatieve number and not positive then I want to see:

```
"this is not valid"

Do you want to try again <y/n>?
```

I've already tried a lot of combination with if, if else but then I don't see that `"do you want to try again?"` or I see both of them and result.

This is not valid and maximum value is: 0

That is not good.

```
int invoer;
int max;
string repeat;

Console.WriteLine("Please give a positive number.\nIf you enter a negative number its not going to work");

do
{
    invoer = 0;
    max = 0;
    repeat = "";

    for (int i = 1; invoer >= 0; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(i + "> ");
        invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (max < invoer)
            max = invoer;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Maximum value is: " + max);
    Console.WriteLine("do you want to try again? y/n: ");
    repeat = Console.ReadLine();
} while (repeat == "y" || repeat == "Y");
```

Comment: Kindly fix the indentation first!

Comment: You need to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` and look at the bool result to see if you need to ask again.

Comment: yeah that was the answer. thanks @RBarryYoung. Now i know that "want to" have less letters then wanna. bravo

Comment: @hvd Or maybe it's the difference between "letters" and "characters"?  To say nothing of "character".  :)

Comment: @hvd Uhmm... Right, need more coffee...

Comment: Your prompt does not match code, you ask for positive number but accept 0 too. Also, using for loop like that is unusual (some would say ugly), it is better to use while loop when condition does not use loop counter variable.

Answer (score 2):

I edited this code for you. It asks the users an unlimited about of time what the positive value is. It only gives the max if the value entered is the max. And it doesn't give the max if the value is negative... I believe this is what you want?

However, this code is horrible. I fixed what I could with it. If it isnt what you are looking for then just scrap it and start new because the ugliness of the way this is operating makes it more difficult to run than it should be.

If this is the answer then please check so.

```
    int invoer;
    int max;
    string repeat;

    Console.WriteLine("Please give a positive number.\nIf you enter a negative number its not going to work");

    do
    {
        invoer = 0;
        max = 0;
        repeat = "";

        for (int i = 0; invoer >= 0; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + "> ");
            invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (max < invoer)
            {
                max = invoer;
                Console.WriteLine("Maximum value is: " + max);
            }
        }

        if (invoer < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is not valid...");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("do you want to try again? y/n: ");
        repeat = Console.ReadLine();
    } 
    while (repeat == "y" || repeat == "Y");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah but i've already tried this. the result is this is not valid but also the program is trying to find to maximum value.

Comment: yeah But i already tried that. you see also "maximum value =0 " which i dont wanna see.

Comment: @user2880279 Also, you might want to implement a means to exit the program. It may not be required for your HW assignment, and I don't know, but it would be good practice for you.

Comment: hey sorry but your code is not correct. Why? Because if the user for example 5 wrote then it says: maximum value 5. then he will jump to number 2 then again he will try do find to maximum value. Console.WriteLine("Maximum value is: " + max); is have to go outside of the loop

Comment: @user2880279 I do not know what you mean by that? To see how a program works, hold F11  in Visual Studios and it will take you through the program step by step. It does not go outside of the loop? It just is not going to print what the max value is every time you enter an integer. That would be repetitive and get old quickly. If you did want it for whatever reason there are a lot of ways you can add it. But I checked that code just now, and it works just as you requested.

Comment: nope. What if the user gives first pozitive number and then negative number. we will see: this is not valid.

Comment: @user2880279 You need to edit your question. What you originally asked apparently has a lot more strings attached to it than what is currently written.

Answer (score 0):

You should use uint.TryParse instead of int.Parse. It will not accept negative numbers and will not throw an exception on invalid input.

Comment: but the problem is, i don't know what TryParse is. This is kind of a homework. I can't use any other codes that i didn't learn it.

Comment: Are you sure you have not learned about [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use int.TryParse, you can always make sure your input is numeric before parsing it:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var number = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) ? input : "0";

var numeralExpression = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(\d|-\d)$");

if (numeralExpression.IsMatch(number))
{
    invoer = int.Parse(number);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that but as i said before this is too complicated for my level. All i want to do is. İf the first value negative is, the program has to offer to do it again...and show an error message. Like this is not valid. do you wanna try again.